# Вывод данных в input через компонент Typeahead

Tags: angular2, angular

На странице используется компонент [*Typehead*](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples)
Есть массив данных, который выводятся в этом компоненте:

```
[{id: 1, address: 'cat'}, {id: 2, address: 'dog'}]
```

Данные в списке выводятся как положено, но если кликнуть на элемент списка, то в *input* выводится *[object Object]*:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как вывести *address* выбранного в списке объекта?
При этом не использовать *ng-template*, так как я думаю что это слишком неоправданным для такой простой задачи.

---

Компонент настроен следующим образом:

Html:

```
<input
    id="typeahead-focus"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="model"
    [ngbTypeahead]="search"
    (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
    (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
    [resultFormatter]="formatter"
    #instance="ngbTypeahead"
/>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ct-typeahead',
  templateUrl: './typeahead.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typeahead.component.sass']
})
export class TypeaheadComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any;
    values: any[];
    formatter = (result: any) => result.address;

    constructor() { 
        this.values = [{id: 1, address: 'cat'}, {id: 2, address: 'dog'}]
    }

    ngOnInit() { }

    @ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
    focus$ = new Subject<string>();
    click$ = new Subject<string>();

    search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
        const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
        const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
        const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

        return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
            map(term => (term === '' ? this.values
                : this.values.filter(v => v.address.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)))
        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых у меня возник вопрос откуда берется переменная `searchString` внутри функции `indexOf`, но то ладно.

Во-вторых `ngModel` это здорово, но `input` не понимает, что такое объект и приводит объект к строке `({}).toString() => [object Object]`. Если добавить вот такой геттер в компонент:

```
public get value(): string {
    if (this.model && this.model.address) {
        return this.model.address;
    }

    return this.model;
}
```

И использовать байндинг атрибута на `input`:

```
<input .... [value]="value">
```

`model` станет объектом после клика на кнопку `dropdown-item`, а до этого `model` это строка, когда вы вводите что-то в сам `input`.

Либо же можно использовать байндинг `inputFormatter`. Если `fomatter` используется для форматирования результатов поиска, то `inputFormatter` используется для форматирования выбранного значения и отображения его в `input`.

Comment: Хорошее решение! Я нашел еще кое что. Можно использовать атрибут *inputFormatter*, эффект тот же. В доках с примерами такого не было, но в [доках Аpi компонента](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/api) это есть. Я просто добавил `[inputFormatter]="formatter"`. Возможно это стоит добавить в ответ.

Comment: @Max, обновил ответ